# Request user input in bash_profile alias command

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

Is there anyway to stop in a bash_profile alias command and prompt for a user input? I'm fairly new to writing terminal commands.

I'm making a custom command that will take 2 inputs and edit my host files and set up vhosts for me on my local machine, at the moment i'm just passing the arguments into the command

```
 addSite mywebsite.co.uk
```

But ideally I would like to be able to just run `addSite`, then the command stops and prompts 'Please enter the domain for your new site'.

Is this possible? If not, can someone point me in the right direction to be able to write a custom terminal command that can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ask for user input with `read` and pass a prompt with the `-p` flag. After the command, you specify the variable name. Then access it like any other variable.

```
read -p 'Please enter the domain for your new site: ' domain
echo Your domain name: $domain
```

**EDIT**: as pointed out by @tripleee in the comments, it's worth noting that this will have unintended side effects if a shell is launched from another source e.g. if you launch an executable file from Finder.

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I was looking for! Thanks, i'll accept your answer as soon as I can!

Comment: Doing this from your shell startup files unconditionally is almost certainly a bad idea, though.

Comment: So just to be sure, as long as I only ever run a function containing this code via the terminal ill be ok?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. With no condition checking, you will always be prompted for this input when opening a new Terminal window. The problems arise when the shell is launched by something not interactive. If you double-click an executable in Finder, it runs `/path/to/command; exit` in a new shell. But since it's asking for user input when it's not going to receive it, it will affect this behavior. In this case, it'll probably think `/path/to/command; exit` is your domain and then it won't launch the file you clicked on.